# Django form is saved but result field is empty in database

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

Django form is saved but "result" field is showing empty in database.
Even after populating the filed from admin panel, it is saved but it still shows empty.

Models.py

```
class Result(models.Model):

    class Choises(models.TextChoices):
        POSITIVE = "POSITIVE", "Positive"
        NEGATIVE = "NEGATIVE", "Negative"
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None)
    result = models.CharField(max_length = 100, choices=Choises.choices, blank=False
    )
    resultDoc = models.ImageField(upload_to='testResults', height_field=None, width_field=None,)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Forms.py

```
class resultForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Result
        fields = ['name', 'result', 'resultDoc']
```

views.py

```
def inputResult(request, pk):
    user = User.objects.filter(id=pk).first()
    profile = newProfile.objects.filter(user=user).first()
    if profile == None:
        profile = oldProfile.objects.filter(user=user).first()
    rForm = resultForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        rForm = resultForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if rForm.is_valid():
            order = rForm.save(commit=False)
            order.user_id = pk
            order.save()
            return redirect('stored_records')
    else:
        rForm = resultForm()
    context = {'user' : user, 'profile':profile, 'rForm': rForm}
    return render(request, 'Testing booth End/input-result-customer-info.html', context)
```

input-result-customer-info.html

```
      <form action="" method = "POST" enctype= "multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="name" class="form-label">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Uploaded By/Doctor Name">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="result" class="form-label">Result</label>
          

          <select class="form-select" id="result"  name="result" class="form-control">
              <option value="POSITIVE">Positive</option>
              <option value="NEGATIVE">Negative</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
          <label>Upload Scan File</label>
          <div class="upload d-flex justify-content-between">
              <div class="file-placeholder">Upload Scan File</div>
              <input type="file" class="form-control d-none" id="resultDoc" name="resultDoc" >
              <label for="resultDoc" class="form-label cam-img"> <img src="{% static 'user/images/Camera.png' %}">  </label>
          </div>
      </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary w-50 ms-auto d-block h-100" type="submit">Upload</button>
      </form>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUO2D.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think that the reason this doesnt work is that you created a form (`rForm`) in the backend but then you don't use it in the frontend.
This is how you should render your form in the the frontend:

```
<form method="post">
    {{ rForm.as_p }} # This is the easiest possible implementation
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

If you want to take control of how the form is rendered, then you have to make sure that the input fields are named in the way that your backend expects. You can do it entirely manually or semi-manually, but your field names have to be set correctly or nothing will work.

Example of typical approach, say in case you have several similar text inputs

```
{% for field in rForm %}
    <label for="{{ field.auto_id }}">{{ field.name }}</label>
    <input type="text" name="{{ field.html_name }}" id="{{ field.auto_id }}" />
{% endfor %}
```

Example of fully hands-on approach

```
<select class="form-select" id="{{ rForm.result.auto_id }}"  name="{{ rForm.result.html_name }}" class="form-control">
    <option value="POSITIVE">Positive</option>
    <option value="NEGATIVE">Negative</option>
</select>
```

In order to make sure that the inputs are being parsed correctly, add a print statement in your view to print the POST request:

```
print("Post Request : ", request.POST)
```

From there you will be able to see if the result field is being picked up correctly or if it's being ignored. Usually when fields get ignored is because they are not named correctly or sometimes it's because they fail validation.

If the rest of the data is saved correctly and just `result` is being left out then it's almost for sure an issue with the field name because if the form failed validation it would have aborted the entire operation.

P.S. I just noticed that you select input has the `class` attribute declared twice